# Terraform datadog_monitor query error Invalid formula or variable(s)

Tags: terraform

I'm reaching out for some help with Terraform.

I'm trying to create a DataDog monitor in Terraform. With Terraform plan I get the error:

> 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["Invalid formula or variable(s): unable to parse 100 * (({{query_400_499_status}} / {{query_html_status}}))").by("host "]}

What is wrong with the query in this datadog_monitor?

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "percent_400_499_status_monitor" {
  query              = "formula(\"100 * ((query_400_499_status / query_html_status))\").by(\"host\").last(\"30m\") >= 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this worked

```
"formula(\"(query_500_status / query_html_status) * 100\").last(\"5m\") >= 10"
```